# Accessing SOAP web services with PowerShell

Tags: .net, web-services, powershell, soap, wsdl

Microsoft [suggests](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30548.accessing-soap-web-services-with-powershell.aspx) to call webservicex, but they [seem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48831526/262852) to be down.

Google seems to have moved away from SOAP.

Might there be an existing SOAP service with a WSDL specification to play with from powershell?

Comment: webservicex is not down. the issue in your other question is specific for the `GetWeather` method, and as a I said the webserver respones properly. It's just that the webserver couldn't find any data in the backend. Use any other method or webservice offered by webservicex.

Comment: @vrdse fair enough.  I'll try the other methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.webservicex.net works perfectly fine.

Here an example:

```
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).Proxy.Credentials =  [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
$url = "http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?wsdl"
$webservicex = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $url -namespace WebServiceProxy -Class GlobalWeatherSoap

$webservicex.GetCitiesByCountry("Netherlands")
```

Response:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <Country>Netherlands</Country>
    <City>Amsterdam Airport Schiphol</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Netherlands</Country>
    <City>Maastricht Airport Zuid Limburg</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Netherlands</Country>
    <City>De Bilt</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Netherlands</Country>
    <City>Deelen</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Netherlands</Country>
    <City>Eindhoven</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Netherlands</Country>
    <City>Groningen Airport Eelde</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Netherlands</Country>
    <City>Gilze-Rijen</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Netherlands</Country>
    <City>De Kooy</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Netherlands</Country>
    <City>Leeuwarden</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Netherlands</Country>
    <City>Rotterdam Airport Zestienhoven</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Netherlands</Country>
    <City>Soesterberg</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Netherlands</Country>
    <City>Twenthe</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Netherlands</Country>
    <City>Valkenburg</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Netherlands</Country>
    <City>Volkel</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Netherlands</Country>
    <City>Vlieland</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Netherlands</Country>
    <City>Woensdrecht</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Netherlands Antilles</Country>
    <City>Flamingo Airport, Bonaire</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Netherlands Antilles</Country>
    <City>Hato Airport, Curacao</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Netherlands Antilles</Country>
    <City>Roosevelt Airport Saint Eustatius</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Netherlands Antilles</Country>
    <City>Juliana Airport, Saint Maarten</City>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```